# Typing in TextFormField closes the screen in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, flutter-textformfield

I'm currently working on a Flutter app that involves a dialog with a button. When the button is clicked, a text field should appear, allowing the user to enter their address. However, I'm encountering an issue where as soon as I start typing in the text field, the entire screen closes and the app returns to the home page.

I've tried implementing the text field using a TextFormField widget and have ensured that the controller and decoration are set correctly. I've also added a validator to check if the address field is empty. Despite these efforts, the screen still unexpectedly closes whenever I begin typing.

this is my code:

```
import 'package:clinic/Managers/api_controller.dart';
import 'package:clinic/models/base_response.dart';
import 'package:clinic/models/doctor_model.dart';
import 'package:clinic/utils/utils.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class DoctorProfile extends StatefulWidget {
  DoctorProfile({Key? key, required this.doctor}) : super(key: key);
  DoctorModel doctor;

  @override
  State<DoctorProfile> createState() => _DoctorProfileState();
}

class _DoctorProfileState extends State<DoctorProfile> {
  static final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  TextEditingController bookDateController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController bookTimeController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController addressController = TextEditingController();
  ApiController apiController = ApiController();
  int appointmentType = 0;
  DateTime bookDateTime = DateTime.now();
  bool isDatePicked = false;
  bool isTimePicked = false;
  bool isTypePicked = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  height: 50,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5),
                  child: IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.chevron_left_sharp,
                      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                      size: 30,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundImage:
                      NetworkImage(Utils().getPicture(widget.doctor.img)),

                  radius: 80,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                Text(
                  '${widget.doctor.first_name} ${widget.doctor.last_name}',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 24,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
                Text(
                  '${widget.doctor.specialty}',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      //fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 18,
                      color: Colors.black54),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 16,
                ),
               
                SizedBox(
                  height: 14,
                ),
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 22, right: 22),
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Text(
                    '${widget.doctor.specs}',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 14,
                      color: Colors.black54,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 80,
                ),
                Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 15,
                      ),
                      Icon(Icons.email_outlined),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 20,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.4,
                        child: Text(
                          '${widget.doctor.email}',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 16,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 10,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 12,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 15,
                      ),
                      Icon(Icons.phone_in_talk_sharp),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 11,
                      ),
                      TextButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        child: Text(
                          '${widget.doctor.phone}',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.blue),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 10,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 0,
                ),
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 15,
                      ),
                      Icon(Icons.location_on_outlined),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 20,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        '${widget.doctor.clinic}',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 16,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
               
                SizedBox(
                  height: 50,
                ),
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30),
                  height: 50,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      foregroundColor: Colors.black,
                      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                      elevation: 2,
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      showInformationDialog(context);
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      'Book an Appointment',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 16,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 40,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> showInformationDialog(BuildContext context) async {
    return await showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return StatefulBuilder(builder: (context, setInnerState) {
            return AlertDialog(
              content: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Form(
                    key: _formKey,
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: [
                        TextFormField(
                          readOnly: true,
                          controller: bookDateController,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              labelText: 'Date',
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                              prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.date_range)
                          ),
                          validator: (value){
                            return isDatePicked ? null : 'Pick a date.';
                          },

                          onTap: () async {
                            final pickedDate = await pickDate();
                            if(pickedDate == null){
                              print('Date is null');
                              return;
                            }

                            final dateTime = DateTime(
                              pickedDate.year,
                              pickedDate.month,
                              pickedDate.day,
                            );
                            setInnerState((){
                              bookDateTime = dateTime;
                              bookDateController.text = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(dateTime);
                              isDatePicked = true;
                            });
                            print('Date Time: ${bookDateTime?.year} : ${bookDateTime?.hour}');
                          },
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 12,),
                        TextFormField(
                          readOnly: true,
                          controller: bookTimeController,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              labelText: 'Time',
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide(
                                  color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                                )
                              ),
                              prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.access_time_outlined)
                          ),
                          validator: (value){
                            return isTimePicked ? null : 'Pick a time';
                          },
                          onTap: () async {
                            if(!isDatePicked){
                              Fluttertoast.showToast(
                                msg: "Please pick a date first.",
                                backgroundColor: Colors.black45,
                              );
                              return;
                            }
                            final pickedTime = await pickTime();
                            if(pickedTime == null){
                              return;
                            }
                            final dateTime = DateTime(
                                bookDateTime.year,
                                bookDateTime.month,
                                bookDateTime.day,
                                pickedTime.hour,
                                pickedTime.minute);
                            setInnerState((){
                              bookDateTime = dateTime;
                              bookTimeController.text = DateFormat('HH:mm').format(dateTime);
                              isTimePicked = true;
                            });
                            print('Date Time: ${bookDateTime?.year} : ${bookDateTime?.hour}');
                          },
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 14,),
                        Container(
                          child: Text(
                            "Type",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 18,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                              color: Colors.black45,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 8,),
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                          children: [
                            CustomRadioButton("Online", 1,appointmentType, (value){
                              setInnerState((){
                                appointmentType = value;
                                isTypePicked = true;
                              });
                            }),
                            CustomRadioButton("Home", 2,appointmentType, (value){
                              setInnerState((){
                                appointmentType = value;
                                isTypePicked = true;
                              });
                            }),
                            CustomRadioButton("Clinic", 3,appointmentType, (value){
                              setInnerState((){
                                appointmentType = value;
                                isTypePicked = true;
                              });
                            }),
                          ],
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 8,),
                        // if patient chose home visit, he should enter his address.
                        (appointmentType == 2) ? showAddressField() : Container(),
                      ],
                    )),
              ),
              title: Text('Book Appointment'),
              actions: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: [
                      ElevatedButton(
                        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                          foregroundColor: Colors.black,
                          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                          elevation: 2,
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0),
                          ),
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.of(context).pop();
                        },
                        child: Text(
                          'Cancel',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                            fontSize: 16,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      ElevatedButton(
                        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                          foregroundColor: Colors.black,
                          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                          elevation: 2,
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0),
                          ),
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {
                          if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                            if(!isTypePicked){
                              Fluttertoast.showToast(
                                msg: "Please choose the type"
                              );
                              return;
                            }
                            // Do something like updating SharedPreferences or User Settings etc.
                            sendBookApi();
                          }
                        },
                        child: Text(
                          'Submit',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 16,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),

              ],
            );
          });
        });
  }


  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    bookDateController.dispose();
    bookTimeController.dispose();
    addressController.dispose();
  }


  @override
  void initState() {
    // _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  }

  Widget CustomRadioButton(String text, int index, int appType, Function(int) onChange) {
    return OutlinedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        onChange(index);
      },
      style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)
        ),
        side: BorderSide(
          color: (appType == index) ? Theme.of(context).primaryColor : Colors.black,
          width: (appType == index) ? 2 : 1.5,
        ),

      ),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Text(
          text,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 14,
            fontWeight: (appType == index) ? FontWeight.bold : FontWeight.w500,
            color: (appType == index) ? Theme.of(context).primaryColor : Colors.black,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<DateTime?> pickDate()=> showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: DateTime.now(),
      firstDate: DateTime.now(),
      lastDate: DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 365))
  );

  Future<TimeOfDay?> pickTime() => showTimePicker(
      context: context,
      initialTime: TimeOfDay.now(),
  );

  Widget showAddressField() {
    return TextFormField(
      controller: addressController,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelText: 'Your address',
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(
                color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              )
          ),
          prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.location_on_outlined)
      ),
      validator: (value){
        return value!.isNotEmpty ? null : 'Type your address';
      },

    );
  }

  void sendBookApi(){
    apiController.post(
      url: APIs.BOOK_APPOINTMENT,
      data: {
        'doctor_id' : widget.doctor.id,
        'date_time': DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm').format(bookDateTime).toString(),
        'type': appointmentType,
        'address': addressController.text
    }
    ).then((value) {
      BaseResponse response = BaseResponse.fromJson(value.data);
      Fluttertoast.showToast(
        msg: response.message,
        toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
        fontSize: 16.0,
        backgroundColor: response.result == 'error' ? Colors.redAccent : Colors.green[400],
        gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
        timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
      );
      Navigator.of(context).pop();

    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you try passing a key to the TextFormField using the key parameter. I encountered this issue previously and that seemed to have worked for me.

Comment: @VipinKumarKashyap should i pass the same key of the form or declare a new one???

Comment: Declare a new one

Comment: @VipinKumarKashyap it didn't work!